# excel vlookup on condition (2 rows with same lookup value, but one has blank data, other has data)

Tags: excel, vlookup

Hopefully a simple question here, in Sheet 1, each lookup value has 2 rows.  One row contains a blank value for Column N, and one row contains a numerical value.  I want the vlookup to ONLY pull in the Numerical value, not the blank (it's pulling in the blank now because it's only considering the first value).

Is there a simple way to get this to skip over any row in sheet1 that matches the lookup but returns a blank value?

```
=IF(A2="""","""",VLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet1'!B:N,10,FALSE))
```

So as you can see, if we do a generic vlookup, it will just return the first lookup for column B which will return a blank for Column N.  We want the row with the value.

[image]

Comment: please mock up an example in tabular form and [edit] the post to include it.  It is easier to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks Scott , I just attached some dummy data in a screenshot for context.

Comment: Just use SUMIFS: `=SUMIFS(N:N,B:B,"Lookup1")`